# Firebase: Wrong file when downloading plist

Tags: firebase, xcode8

Instead of getting the "googleservice-info.plist" file, I got a file called "Unkown" when adding an app to a new firebase project I just created. When I later opened the project I got loads of errors so I decided to delete everything, and therefore I can't really give any more information. However, I only wanted to know if this is something that has happened to anyone else, or if it's some major issue that Firebase is aware of? Worth mentioning is that I recently updated to XCode 8 and I have gotten tons of problems regarding Firebase after doing so.

Edit:
The file that is being downloaded is a TextEdit Document instead of a Plist file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problems with Firebase and Xcode (8.1). Bug has been reported to Google & Apple. I used the latest versions of Git,Firebase,Cocoapods, etc...

Furthermore, when I tried to run an App, which was using Firebase (Auth & Database), I've got several errors started with: "Conflicting nullability specifier on return types, 'nullable conflicts' with existing specifier 'nonnull'

Comment: Exactly the same errors as I got! Nice to see that I'm not alone with this issue, thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the file name "unknown" to "Googleservice-info.plist" with extention to "plist" and changing the default opener to xcode by rightclicking and pressing Get Info button worked for me